# Add Back Button to Toolbar in iOS

Tags: ios

Is there some way to add a button (not in a navigation view or something like that) that will perform `back` (meaning, going back to the previous view before the last segue) in an iOS app?

It doesn't have the shape of a back button (it will be fine with simply the word `"Back"` on it).

I want to put something like that in a bottom toolbar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a simple button and in its action do:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: This does not work. Should I do something else to enable this?

Comment: Is the UIViewController embedded in a UINavigationController? Have you placed the UIBarButtonItem in the toolbar already? Is the outlet connected? Please post some code of what you have so far so I can help you more.